# how to insert an entire csv file into SQLite at once

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I created sqlite database table and i would like to populate the database table with a CSV file saved in the sd card.
my question is, is there any method or approach to insert the entire csv file into the sqlite database at once 
instead of inserting it line by line?

Comment: where is your csv file in sdcard or assets folder

Comment: yes first u read csv file using csvreader in android than u insert data in database there is not any directed way to read and save data in database

Comment: This link appears to cover what you are asking [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible right away unless you use a tool like [SQLiteDatabaseBrowser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases):

[image]

If this is not working for you, you can follow the following steps to implement your own import:

1. open the file with `FileOutputStream` to read its contents
2. read the first line (headers) and `STring.split()` items by `,`
3. build an `insert` SQL String based on the items/headers
4. create a `PreparedStatement` from it
5. read all subsequent lines and `String.split()` values by `,`
6. assign bind variables
7. execute your `PreparedStatement`

It's not very difficult and if you don't need the right or best fitting data type that's all.

Good luck!